# Javascript stripping out substring and appending it

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I am trying to do something which should be simple but I'm having no luck.
I have a string like the following:

`<hgc attr="something">late at</hgc>`

and I need to strip out the last `at` prior to the closing html tag and append it, surrounded by its own tag to produce:

`<hgc attr="something">late </hgc><hgb>at</hgb>`

Don't worry about the tags, they are custom.

**Update**

That `at` word may be anything, even `hgc` and I will already have the word ahead of time to produce the appended html.

I have attempted to perform the following:

```
let markup = '<hgb>' + word + '</hgb>';

let applied = $element.html().slice(0, pos) + 
                  $element.html().slice(pos).replace(word, "") +
                  markup;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? What doesn't work (_with an explanation why you think it doesn't work_)? Any errors?

Comment: Is this actually a string or something from the DOM api? Also how *fixed* is this type of input? If it's always like this you could simple strip of the last x chars and append the fixed part.

Comment: No, it is not a fixed string.  `late at` is user input.

Comment: What if the string is `<hgc attr="something">late at best</hgc>`, and you want to extract "at", should it just be that word or should it include everything after that word? "at best"

Comment: I would want `best` extracted.  The word before the `</hgc>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```js
let str = '<hgc attr="something">late at</hgc>';
let reg = /\w+(?=<)/g;

let word = str.match(reg)[0];
str = `${str.split(reg).join('')}<hgb>${word}</hgb>`;

console.log(str);
```

Something like this should work.

Comment: Just what I was looking for.